# How to set password length differently for development and production in devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have a rails password like so in my `devise.rb`:

```
  config.password_length = 8..128
```

I would like to set this to

```
if development?
  config.password_length = 1..128 
else
  config.password_length = 8..128
end
```

But this gives me this error:
`NoMethodError: undefined method`development?' for main:Object`

Comment: Have you tried `Rails.env.development?`?

Comment: @jvillian  Great, that worked!  If you want to write this up as an answer I will accept it.  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you want something more like:

```
if Rails.env.development?
  config.password_length = 1..128 
else
  config.password_length = 8..128
end
```